# Not able to load castra files with from_castra() function of dask

Tags: python-2.7, dask, castra

I am trying to replicate the example of [this](http://blaze.pydata.org/blog/2015/09/08/reddit-comments/) page about castra, dask and reddit comments, and I get the above error when I run the

> dd.from_castra(data,columns)

My castra file took some hours to be created but it is clean and exactly as the tutorial mentions.

Used both my macbook and an Ubuntu instance on amazon AWS and had the same issue.

Same code and file works fine in a windows PC.

Any info could be helpful!

> ValueError: Expected iterable of tuples of (name, dtype), got ['archived', 'author',....]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem. It was a matter of **versions**. If you face the same issue do the follwing:

**Step 1**:

Uninstall dask using pip

```
pip uninstall dask
```

**Step 2**:

Uninstall castra using pip

```
pip uninstall castra
```

**Step 3**:

Install the version of dask which is compatible with castra

```
pip install -Iv dask==0.10.0
```

**Step 4**:

Install castra again

```
pip install castra
```

**Step 5**:

After you install the correct version, check your versions with the following commands

```
pip show dask
pip show castra
```

The versions should be equal to the ones in the screenshot:

[terminal screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zt3aq.png)

Answer (score 0):

Castra was an experimental project and is no longer supported.  See the README https://github.com/blaze/castra#maintenance